# Flash AIR HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

this might seem like a simple question, but I searched the internet to no avail.

I am creating an air app that uses **HTTPService** to connect to a .net api and get a user for example. It works great when I publish the move for "Flash Player 10" as a .swf, however, when I publish it as .air it seems like there is no internet connection at all. I am assuming it's internet securities (maybe firewall). I turned off my firewall and everything that might be blocking the internet access, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: could u debug it and post ur error code ?

Answer (score 0):

Some common problems when you face air

Don't define HTTPService in your methods define it as private var

```
private var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
```

Make your application more linear specially when you face so much streams

When you publish it to .SWF if you test it directly through builder you can't find out the real problem because when you run it while in builder or anything else flash will not face security and sandbox violation but air will